# Migrating from PHP to ASP .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Ive been always using PHP only as a backend language to create websites. Now I want to try something new, and my choice is ASP .NET.

After a little research I found out I need the following knowledge - C#, then .NET framework, then ASP MVC pattern, and then the entity framework.

Is that right?

Can you recommend me some good books on that topics?

Thanks!

Comment: Please see [help/on-topic] for questions which are on-topic for Stack Overflow. Recommendation questions are not on-topic.

Comment: If you want a book review, then pick your favorite book seller and then read the reviews on their site. You need lots of knowledge to develop a site, there's probably not a comprehensive list. Working through tutorials (both online and from books) will give you a solid idea of what you need to learn more about in order to be successful in the areas you wish to be successful.

Comment: Have a look on Microsoft Virtual Academy too as there are loads of good resources for learning the technologies you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book recommendation question is off-topic, but your initial question is not, so I'll answer that one.

Yes, there are a lot of things to learn going from PHP to ASP.NET MVC, especially if you've never done software development in a MVC pattern before. First, I would recommend that you learn about the ASP.NET MVC architecture, then start developing a test site. You can pick up C# and any .NET Framework functions along the way. I think learning by doing is the best way. If you want to use an ORM, then you can learn about EF, otherwise, you can always connect and query the database using ADO.NET.

There are also many great free resources on the web, but personally I do find books to be more useful if I want to master a subject. Hope this helps!

Comment: The initial question *is* off-topic too, because it's opinion based.

Comment: @mason True, but so are a lot of the questions on SO. Even questions like "What is the best way to sort ..." or "Recommended strategies to implement ..." are opinion based. I chose to answer because there might be others out there asking the same question.